# Hook for page Request?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, actions

I want to run a function that looks at the current url params of the page that is requested and sets a cookie based on those params.

So, I guess I'm looking for:

1. The Wordpress Hook that allows me to do this before the page is even loaded
2. A way to get the requested URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Kick in right before theme takes over, when WP is all loaded
add_action('wp', function(){
    list($uri, $qs) = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    // Do stuff here:
    // ... STUFF ...
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, what does the list($uri, $qs) do?

Comment: Extracts the URI and Query-String from current Request URI. (E.g.: http://domain.tld/uri?qs translates to $uri = '/uri' and $qs = 'qs')